# Radius of convergence of unknown function

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-numbers, complex-integration

I am a bit stuck on this, I think it is kind of easy, but I feel dumb because I don't see it.
 Also I think something is wrong in the question.

Let $\{a_n\}_n \subseteq \mathbb{C}$ such that $\underset{n}{lim}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}{5}$ and $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n = i$. Calculate the radius of convergence of the series $\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}} a_n(z-1)^{2n}$ and the value of

$$
\int_{C(0,3)}\frac{f(z)}{z-2} dz
$$
with $f(z)=\underset{n=0}{\overset{\infty}{\sum}}a_n(z-1)^{2n}$.

I have tried with Cauchy's integral formula, but there are some things that don't fit.

Comment: $R=5$ and the integral is $(2\pi i) f(2)=-2\pi$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From $\underset{n}{lim}\sqrt[n]{a_n}=\frac{1}{5}$ is straightforward that the radius of convergence is $R=5$. Now by the Cauchy's integral formula, since $2\in \operatorname{int}C(0,3)$,
$$\int_{C(0,3)}\frac{f(z)}{z-2} dz=2\pi i f(2)=2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n(2-1)^{2n}=2\pi i\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n=2\pi i i=-2\pi.$$

Comment: but it shouldn't be the case that $1/R=\underset{n}{lim}\sqrt[2n]{a_n}$
 and so $R=\sqrt{5}$? I think this was the thing that was wrong in the setting of the question. I knew that something was off, because at the time in the exam where I got this question, some classmate said that something wasn't right.

Comment: Well, as I believe the situation went, by thinking about it, I think the professor said that we had to change the 5 by a 25, that would make everything work in the first place. Either way, thank you for your answer.